WCF File Upload Limit - Unable to Upload Files Larger Than 4MB
I am working with a WCF service and client on the .NET Framework 4.8, and I am encountering an issue where I can't upload files larger than 4MB. The default size seems to be 4MB, and I need to increase this limit to allow larger file uploads (e.g., 10MB or more).
Here is the current configuration on the server side:
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="05:00:00" openTimeout="05:00:00" closeTimeout="05:00:00" sendTimeout="05:00:00">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  </binding>
</webHttpBinding>

And the configuration on the client side:
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="wsHttpAdminEndpoint" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>

Despite these settings, I still cannot upload files larger than 4MB. I have also checked the IIS settings and increased the maxAllowedContentLength, but the issue persists.
Can anyone suggest what I might be missing or any other settings I need to configure to allow file uploads greater than 4MB?
What I have already tried:

Increased maxReceivedMessageSize and maxBufferSize.
Checked IIS and application settings for maximum request size.
Added httpRuntime settings in web.config.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The WCF binding configuration is still subject to the limits set in the  configuration.  Try setting this in your web.config:
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" maxRequestLength="[desired upload size]" />
</system.web>

The upper limit for that setting is the same as the upper limit for the settings you've already adjusted in your WCF binding configuration.

You can try to add requestlimits tag in Web.config. For example :
<location path="Documents/Upload">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> 
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>

